# Export XML to SQL Database (Complicated XML)

Tags: c#, xml, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, window

I have XML which very complicated in structure, as below. My objective is to get all the data from the XML, dump into database as relational structure. What is the best way to achieve it using c#.

```
<a> 
   <b>
        <c> 
            <d>
                <e>....
                <e>
                <e>
            </d>
            <d>
            </d>
        </c>
     </b>

   <b>
        <c> 
            <d>
                <e>....
                <e>
                <e>
            </d>
            <d>
            </d>
        </c>
     </b>
</a>
```

Comment: This is way too broad a question.  [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?  I suggest you start by looking at sites like [this](http://www.akamarketing.com/blog/135-importing-xml-into-sql-server-table-aspnet.html)

Comment: I'm just starting the work, i just want to know the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

As an exercise create classes for each node type.

Aka

```
class A
{
public B[] Bs; <- one-to-many
}

class B
{
public C C; <- one-to-one
}

class C
{
public D[] Ds; <- one-to-many
}
```

etc.  With that you can start to see the relationships between classes and what goes into each class.  Each class is potentially a table in the relational database.  Since class A is really the root node, it probably isn't a table, but there for completeness.